# withTranslation HOC looks for translation in first namespace only

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I'm upgrading my project from `i18next^11.0.0` to `i18next^15.0.0` and `react-i18next^7.0.0` to `react-i18next^10.0.0`. I was using `translate` HOC previously but seems that it's replaced by [withTranslation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc) now. So my simple React component after these changes looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const AboutControl = props => {
  const { t } = props;

  return (
    <div className="about-control">
      <p className="about-control-application-name">
        {t('name')} {VERSION}
      </p>

      <p>
        {t('supported-browsers')}:
      </p>

      <ul>
        <li>Google Chrome >= 55</li>
        <li>Mozilla Firefox >= 53</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withTranslation(['about', 'application'])(AboutControl);
```

Translation for `supported-browsers` key is defined in `about` namespace while translation for `name` key is in `application` namespace. However new version of the library doesn't translate `name` key in the example above:

[image]

If I change an order of `about` and `application` in `withTranslation` call

```
export default withTranslation(['application', 'about'])(AboutControl);
```

everything becomes vice versa (`supported-browsers` is not translated):

[image]

In older version of `react-i18next` [nsMode option was available](https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/withnamespaces#withnamespaces-options) that solved the issue but it doesn't work anymore:

```
await i18next.init({
  whitelist: this.languages,
  lng: this.language || this.languages[0],
  fallbackLng: this.languages[0],
  lowerCaseLng: true,
  debug: false,
  resources: {},
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false // not needed for React
  },
  react: {
    wait: true,
    nsMode: true
  }
});
```

I didn't find anything related to this in [documentation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc#loading-namespaces). Here is an example from there:

```
// load multiple namespaces
// the t function will be set to first namespace as default
withTranslation(['ns1', 'ns2', 'ns3'])(MyComponent);
```

Looks like that no any additional options are required otherwise I wonder what namespaces should be passed for if not to translate texts of a component. Is it a bug? Or does any workaround exist?

[Migration guide from 9 to 10](https://react.i18next.com/latest/migrating-v9-to-v10) doesn't highlight any changes on this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-i18next` didn't have `nsMode` since version `10.0.0`. But [this pull request](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/pull/822) adds it back (published in `10.7.0`).

One could translate texts (even without passing namespaces to `withTranslation` or `useTranslation`) just by prefixing keys by namespace (`ns:key`):

```
import React from 'react';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const AboutControl = props => {
  const { t } = props;

  return (
    <div className="about-control">
      <p className="about-control-application-name">
        {t('application:name')} {VERSION}
      </p>

      <p>
        {t('about:supported-browsers')}:
      </p>

      <ul>
        <li>Google Chrome >= 55</li>
        <li>Mozilla Firefox >= 53</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withTranslation()(AboutControl);
```

Passing namespaces to `withTranslation` is required when you [load translation resources asynchronously](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/820#issuecomment-482003156) to ensure that they are available before rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem described (the ns specified in withTranslation function was omitted) and after looking for a solution and not finding anything, I tried something different and it was the right solution.

Instead of prefix keys by namespace, you can configure the namespace to use using:

**const {t} = useTranslation ('yourNSname');**

You can continue using the prefix keys to access values ​​from other namespaces.

I hope it helps you or someone with the same problem.